# How to convert a list in string form to a list

Tags: python

Suppose a string `s="[1,2,3]"`

I want the list to be `l=[1,2,3]`, where `type(l)` is `list`

How can I achieve this

Comment: Have a look at [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (and don't use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval))

Comment: try `l = eval(s)`

Comment: try this:

    `l = s.strip('[]').split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
In [3]:  l = eval(s)

In [4]: print l
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You shouldn't suggest [very dangerous functions like `eval`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) when there are better options.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

s="[1,2,3]"
s_list = json.loads(s)
print(type(s_list))
```

out:

```
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: this won't work with s="[1,2,'abn']"